# Fetch data from xml source in SSIS failed because The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized

Tags: xml, ssis

I am trying to load into SQL Server data from XML source with an URL as "XML location". 
SSIS give me back an error message like "The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized" even if I set-up an HTTP Connection Manager where the credential login is fine.
Any advice about how correctly linked or process the "credential login" before to run the XMLSource?

## SSIS Package details:

Control Flow: (1) Data Flow Task
Data Flow Task: Contain (1) XML Source
Connection manager: (1) HTTP Connection Manager
Extra info below available:
The XML file is remote in an URL like that:
http://mywebsite/mywebsite-services/exportservice.svc/launchFull/Ireland
The website is usually accessible login with Single Sign On.
So what I did is to: 
1_ set-up an SSIS  project with a Web Service Task (login credential from HTTP conn manager). 
2_ add Data flow task with XML source.
But seems like the credential login from the web service doesn;t work fro the XML task.

Comment: Can you give a example of your attempt?

Comment: More info added in the question posted.

Comment: I'm not using SSIS anymore, all solved writing in Python.